# How to export using DATA_PUMP to S3 bucket?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, rds

We have RDS (Oracle) instance, I need to export specific Schema into dumpfile. Export works and copies dump file into DATA_PUMP_DIR. Issue is that RDS do not have file directory access.

I need exported DMP file either on S3 or copy to another EC2 instance.

The article: [LINK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html) talks about copying data dump file between two RDS instances but not to S3 or EC2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Third option.** I am using it.

1. Take a look at [alexandria-plsql-utils](https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils) project, and especially look at: `amazon_aws_auth_pkg`, `amazon_aws_s3_pkg` and `ftp_util_pkg` packages.
2. Install required packages and dependencies.
3. Do your dump, then with such example code below you can copy file from Amazon RDS Oracle into S3 bucket.

   ```
   declare
      b_blob blob;
   begin
      b_blob := file_util_pkg.get_blob_from_file ('DATA_PUMP_DIR', 'my_dump.dmp');
      amazon_aws_auth_pkg.init ('aws_key_id','aws_secret', p_gmt_offset => 0);
      amazon_aws_s3_pkg.new_object('my-bucket-name', 'my_dump.dmp', b_blob, 'application/octet-stream');
    end;
   ```

   `

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this problem.
**First option.**

1. Install a free database version of the Oracle XE version on EC2
   instance(It is very easy and fast)
2. Export a schema from the RDS instance to DATA_PUMP_DIR
   directory. Use `DBMS_DATAPUMP` package  or run `expdp user/pass@rds` on EC2 to create a dump file.
3. Create database link on RDS instance between RDS DB and Oracle XE
   DB.

> If you are creating a database link between two DB instances inside
>   the same VPC or peered VPCs the two DB instances should have a valid
>   route between them.
>   [Adjusting Database Links for Use with DB Instances in a VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.Database.html#Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.DBLinks)

4. Copy the dump files from RDS instance to Oracle XE DB on EC2 uses
   the `DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE` via database link
5. Copy files from the `DATA_PUMP_DIR` directory Oracle XE on EC2 instance to the S3.

**Second option.**
Use the obsolete utility `exp` to export. It has restrictions on the export of certain types of data and is slower.

1. Run `exp user/password@rds` on EC2 instance.
2. Copy files from the directory Oracle XE on EC2 instance to the S3

> Original export is desupported for general use as of Oracle Database
>   11g. The only supported use of Original Export in 11g is backward
>   migration of XMLType data to a database version 10g release 2 (10.2)
>   or earlier. Therefore, Oracle recommends that you use the new Data
>   Pump Export and Import utilities, except in the following situations
>   which require Original Export and Import:
>   [Original Export and Import](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm#g1070082)

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to directly access a S3 bucket from a Oracle database. Please have a look at the following documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/oracle-s3-integration.html

And here the official news that this is supported: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/02/Amazon-RDS-for-Oracle-Now-Supports-Amazon-S3-Integration/?nc1=h_ls

It seems that the first post was a little bit to early to get this news. But anyway this post lists further good solutions like the database link.

Answer (score 0):

Once the datapump export resides in the oracle DIRECTORY it is SIMPLE to push it to S3!

Use: rdsadmin.rdsadmin_s3_tasks

A similar approach is used to first pull a datapump file to the oracle DIRECTORY, then use datapump to import it.  Either DBMS_DATAPUMP or impdp is able to reference the file in the directory.