# How to write a binary file from AWS RDS Oracle database directory to local file system

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, export, amazon-rds, dump

How to write a binary file from AWS RDS Oracle database directory to local file system on `EC2`. I tried using Perl script with `UTL_FILE`, but it can't find read the file. Getting the permissions error.

Comment: Please edit the question and paste the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS RDS Oracle, you do not have access to the file system.

If you need access to the file system then you need to use instance EC2 and install the ORACLE RDBMS.

Comment: Actually I want to generate data pump export from AWS Oracle RDS and provide it to another team as a file is there any alternate solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794500/how-to-export-using-data-pump-to-s3-bucket/48801374

Answer (score 0):

AWS has an option to integrate with S3:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/oracle-s3-integration.html
You could upload your files there and then download to your local machine. Here are steps to use it with Datapump:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html#Oracle.Procedural.Importing.DataPumpS3.Step1